# IIS not loading css file outside of website folder

Tags: html, css, iis

I have an ASP 4.0 web site being served by IIS 8 that is in a folder outside of wwwroot.  The site will load, but a css file that I am using is not being loaded (getting a 404 error).

Here's the folder path for the site:
C:/Sites/Test/"website I am using"

And the folder path for the css file:
C:/Sites/Test/sharedfiles/css/stylesheet.css

Here's the link I am using to connect to the css file (with spaces to get this to post)
    < link href="~/../sharedfiles/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" / >

This should load the css file, but it does not.  I'd like to figure out how to get this working.

The Sites folder is shared for IIS_IUSRS and IUSR and permissions are passed down to the folders below, including the Test/sharedfiles/css folder.

The web site folder is what's selected by IIS for the website.  I have Anonymous Authentication enabled for Application Pool identity and Static File serving is enabled.

I'd appreciate any other ideas on how to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sharedfiles a virtual directory and establish a web site or a web application there and access your resources (css etc.) using a url. So in local host you would have http://localhost/sharedfiles/yourcss.css

Thats the correct way to do it - what you are trying to implement here is your own CDN.

Comment: Is there a way to still keep a relative path for this?  I ask because this is a test site I am working on, but the production site path would be C:/Sites/Prod/"website I am using".  That means my options are:

1.  use the same layout, having a C:/Sites/Prod/sharedfiles/css folder.  Then I'll have to create two virtual directories, one for each shared folder, and have the url be different for each one and hardcoded into my page.

Comment: 2.  Have a separate sharedfiles section, something like C:/Sites/sharedfiles.  I could break it down to Sites/sharedfiles/Test and Sites/sharedfiles/Prod, so I could create a single virtual directory to make all of the contents accessible, but then I still run into the problem of having a different url between Test and Prod content.

Comment: I think I'm going to try option 2: it makes the most sense for growth.  However, I'm still stuck on trying to come up with a relative url to access the css.  I think it should be possible if I know each site will be /Sites/(Prod or Test)/"website" and the css files will be /Sites/sharedfiles/(Prod or Test)/css/stylesheet.css.  I'm still looking into this, but I'd appreciate any input to handle this last hurdle.